# Unable to install Anaconda on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, bash, software-installation, python-2.7

I am trying to install Anaconda on my Ubuntu 16.04. I downloaded the .sh file from [here](https://www.continuum.io/downloads). I ran `bash Anaconda2-4.3.1-Linux-x86_64.sh` as the page says and I got this error

```
./Anaconda2-4.3.1-Linux-x86_64.sh: line 493: /home/anantha/anaconda2/pkgs/python-2.7.13-0/bin/python: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
ERROR:
cannot execute native linux-64 binary, output from 'uname -a' is:
Linux anantha-X556UQK 4.4.0-31-generic #50-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jul 13 00:06:14 UTC 2016 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux
```

How do I move forward from here? I did this a couple of times and each time, I deleted the folder(named anaconda2) in which I think this was getting installed. I hope that won't conflict with any future installations.

Comment: Looks like you need the [32-bit installer](https://repo.continuum.io/archive/Anaconda2-4.3.1-Linux-x86.sh)

Comment: Oh!  I had just re-installed Ubuntu and I installed the 32-bit by accident. Thank you.